# Undefined is not an object evaluating RNGooglesignin.dark

Tags: react-native

So I am trying to run my react-native project but I am getting this error. Please help

[image]

Answer (score -1):

go the files GoogleSignin.ios.js and GoogleSignin.android.js which are located in
node_modules/react-native-google-signin/src/) and replace the following values:

```
GoogleSigninButton.Size = {
Icon: RNGoogleSignin.BUTTON_SIZE_ICON,
Standard: RNGoogleSignin.BUTTON_SIZE_STANDARD,
Wide: RNGoogleSignin.BUTTON_SIZE_WIDE
};
GoogleSigninButton.Color = {
Auto: RNGoogleSignin.BUTTON_COLOR_AUTO,
Light: RNGoogleSignin.BUTTON_COLOR_LIGHT,
Dark: RNGoogleSignin.BUTTON_COLOR_DARK
};
```

with:

```
GoogleSigninButton.Size = {
Icon: '48 x 48',
Standard: '230 x 48',
Wide: '312 x 48'
};

GoogleSigninButton.Color = {
Auto: 'white',
Light: 'blue',
Dark: 'grey'
};
```